# How to find average/expected time for given expression?

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

```
(n * log_2 n) + (n^1.01 * (log_2 n)^10)
```

and is it better than `O(n^1.03)` ? If yes can one please explain, how to get an average case when worst case is known ?

Answer (score 2):

In theory, yes. `O(n^p)` is larger than `O(n*log n)` and `O((log n)^k)` for any `p > 1` and `k > 0`.

For the first: `n^p > (n * log n) <=> n^(p-1) > log n`

For the second: `n^p > (log n)^k <=> n^(p/k) > log n`

Both of these inequalities hold for sufficiently large `n`.

Also notice that the base of the logarithm is irrelevant, because logs of different bases only differ by a constant factor, since `log_b(x) = log_e(x)/log_e(b)`.

On the other hand, the only thing you can say about the average case, based on worst-case alone, is that it's no worse than the worst case.

A practical remark: for `n^1.03` to become twice as large as `n^1.01`, you need `(n^1.03)/(n^1.01) = 2 <=> n^0.02 = 2 <=> n = 2^50`. That's huge!

Comment: Thanks, can you also point how to compare O(n*log n) and O((log n)^k) ? or I believe, "For the first" and second" statements are enough to compare ?

Comment: You can write it as `O(n) > O((log n)^(k-1)) <=> O(n^(1/(k-1))) > O(log n)`. The LHS is a polynomial. In general, `log n` is smaller than `n` regardless of their exponent, e.g. you can see that `n*log n` is larger than `n`, and `n` vs. `(log n)^k` is equivalent to `n^(1/k)` vs. `log n`.